# LNK2019 error using Nite and OpenNI

Tags: openni

I haven't ever seen the error of LNK 2019 before and now I encounter it when i try to link the code that i get from Nite.

The error is...

```
1>kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__niteShutdownHandTracker referenced in function "public: void __thiscall nite::HandTracker::destroy(void)" (?destroy@HandTracker@nite@@QAEXXZ)
1>kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__niteStartHandTracking referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::HandTracker::startHandTracking(class nite::Point3f const &,short *)" (?startHandTracking@HandTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@ABVPoint3f@2@PAF@Z)
1>kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__niteReadHandTrackerFrame referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::HandTracker::readFrame(class nite::HandTrackerFrameRef *)" (?readFrame@HandTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@PAVHandTrackerFrameRef@2@@Z)
1>kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__niteHandTrackerFrameRelease referenced in function "public: void __thiscall nite::HandTrackerFrameRef::release(void)" (?release@HandTrackerFrameRef@nite@@QAEXXZ)
1>kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__niteStartGestureDetection referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::HandTracker::startGestureDetection(enum nite::GestureType)" (?startGestureDetection@HandTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@W4GestureType@2@@Z)
1>D:\AcerUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\kinect\Debug\kinect.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you get error LNK2019 from Visual Studio Console output, you might building your project for Win32 platform on your 64bit Windows, try swiching to x64.

   IF you are Using Visual Studio    GO TO ->Build --> (thats where you change or create  win32/x64
    **Configuration Manager[image]**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your application is being linked against the corresponding libraries?
Somewhere in your OpenNI and Nite installation, there must be a folder containing .lib files. You have to specify this path in the additional library directories in your project's property page. If it still doesn't work afterwards, you should add the names of these libraries in the additional dependencies.